# MongoDB to slow inserting data which contains nested arrays

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I tried to insert new data to mongodb, but insertion too slow.
If I try to insert to fresh collection everything fine, so I think there are some limitation, may be I can fix it with re-configuring mongo.

Insert row:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5c2cc847d195177646721cd8"),
"startTime" : 1.546405302e+15.0,
"blocks" : [ 
    {
        "deltas" : [ 
            1, 
            0, 
            0, 
            8, 
            127, 
            127, 
            127,
            ...
            N
         ]
      },
      {
        "deltas" : [ 
            1, 
            0, 
            0, 
            8, 
            127, 
            127, 
            127,
            ...
            N
         ],
        ...
        N
    },
    ...
   ]
}
```

blocks key  usually contains 100 elements.

deltas key usually contains 1000 elements.

Collection has around 28k rows like above.

Collection stats:
[image]

Any ideas how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend embedding large arrays in your documents, as this is somewhat know that large embedded array affect performance in Mongodb.

One of the ways you could have faster writes is to disable [write concerns](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/write-concern/#write-concern-specification) this would basically not wait for acknowledgement from MongoDB server. This could be a little risky there are some [caveats](https://scalegrid.io/blog/mongodb-write-concern-3-must-know-caveats/)  that you should know about, follow the links for more info on these.

Comment: thank you, yes, I know that embedding large arrays  affect on performance, but I what to do, its a client requirement =)

Answer (score 0):

Adding additional data to documents makes mongodb to reinsert documents to free space. If your arrays have max length try to use capped collection.